# Text cursor has strange shape in Firefox

Tags: firefox, text-cursor

Sometimes my text cursor in Firefox changes shape. Normally it is a straight vertical line, but sometimes there is additional short horizontal line near the top:

[image]

It does not happen for all text boxes. It also does not happen in other applications.

What happened? In what situation such cursor would be used?

I think this started after I was trying out different display languages in Windows. But when I returned to original language the original cursor didn't go back. Is that cursor maybe used in one of languages that I tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible explanation is that this is the cursor for internationalized language,
where text can be mixed for languages of different directions.

If you had installed a language whose direction was left-to-right,
together with another whose direction was right-to-left, the caret with the dash
indicates the typing direction for the current language.

*Comment by user mareko* : For those who are annoyed by this cursor I found out how to toggle it manually : go to `about:config` and toggle `bidi.browser.ui`.

Comment: I did some digging in Firefox source code and found where it is drawn: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/3c08edf74d039af79f9daad8ff5b57ffb64fdab6/layout/base/nsCaret.cpp#534 So you were right that this is language direction indicator. But still, I think this should not be shown in that case.

Comment: Indeed, the code works heavily with [Bidirectional text (Bidi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_text).

Comment: For those who are annoyed by this cursor I found out how to toggle it manually: go to about:config and toggle bidi.browser.ui

Comment: @mareko Should have posted your comment as an answer so easier to see and get upvotes